# Evaluate $\log_{5}19^2 / (\log_{3}15)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Evaluate $(\log_{5}19^2)/(\log_{3}15)$

I did this, but I get $1.484$, whereas it's $1.038$ in my book.

I used the method:

$\log_{a}b = \frac{\log_{c}b}{\log_{c}a}$

Comment: $\log_{5}(19^2) / \log_{3}(15) \approx 1.484$ while $(\log_{5}19)^2 / \log_{3} 15 \approx 1.358$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the law of logarithms:

$$\log_{n}(x^{a})\equiv a \log_{n}(x)$$

We have your expression:

$$\frac{2\log_{5}(19)}{\log_{3}(15)}$$

Writing these in terms of the natural logarithm $\ln(\cdot)$, we have (using a calculator or tables):

$$2\frac{\ln(19)}{\ln(5)}\times \frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(15)}\approx 1.4843$$

So your book does appear to be wrong.